# Grails CommandObject validating when it should fail

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, command-objects

I have the following Command Object in my Grails 2.2.3 application.

```
@Validateable
class PictureCommand {

    MultipartFile picture
    String notes
    Boolean isDocument

    static constraints = {
        picture nullable: false, validator: { val ->
            if (!val.contentType in ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif','image/bmp'])
                return 'fileType.invalid'
        }
        notes nullable: true
        isDocument nullable: true
    }
}
```

This allows for uploading a picture file, and ensures that it is in the list of valid types. The problem, however, is I can upload files that are NOT in that list. When I call `cmd.validate()` I get `true`, then I call `cmd.hasErrors()` and get `false`. I have tried returning the String `'fileType.invalid'` and the List `['fileType.invalid']` and neither work. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some parentheses to get the correct operator order:

```
if (!(val.contentType in ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif','image/bmp']))
```

Currently it's evaluating `!val` first, and that's always true if it's not null or blank.

Comment: I remember struggling with this few years back.